Correlation between modern cosmology and the buddhist cosmology
Has any expert tried to draw correlation between the modern cosmology and the Buddhist cosmology? The modern cosmology talks about other planets, galaxies, black holes and the observable universe. So where does that leave the 31 planes of existence? I have always tried to map where it fits.
Do the 31 planes of existence constitute the planes that are on and above planet earth? The Buddhist scripture mentions thousands of Cakkavala or world system, does it imply innumerable number of planets similar to that of earth and each having its own 31 planes of existence? So are these other 'earths' so to speak, in other galaxies or extremely distant from our planet earth? What is going on?

Isn't this the same as previous [tag:buddhist-cosmology] questions e.g. On 31 planes of existence etc.?

These 31 planes, I would guess they are like some kind of 'cessation of a substantial reality', although I have read that reality has no limit..
